# Solow growth model on firms level

Tags: economic-growth, solow

Probably a silly question, but I just have to make sure. I am wondering whether it is acceptable to use the solow / solow-swan growth model to model the growth of firm instead of growth of an economy?

Comment: The model cannot directly be applied, so please be more clear about what exactly do you mean. Do all consumers buy from this firm? Do they all give the firm their savings? If yes, how is it different from an economy? If not, what exactly happens?

Comment: Also, everything is acceptable given certain standards, but what is your goal with the model, what are you trying to do?